Why do hash functions benefit from being injective, or why are collisions a problem?
I'm a math person, not a CS person. So I'm familiar with functions and injectivity, but having trouble understanding the discussion of hash tables and collisions. I was under the impression that a hash function was typically "one way" in the sense it might be easy to compute, but difficult/impossible to invert.
The following is from Leetcode's introductory course:

When different keys convert to the same integer, it is called a
collision. Without handling collisions, older keys will get overridden
and data will be lost. There are multiple ways to handle collisions,
but here we'll talk about a common one called chaining.
When using chaining, we store linked lists inside the hash map's
array instead of the elements themselves. The linked list nodes store
both the key and the value. If there are collisions, the collided
key-value pairs are linked together in a linked list. Then, when
trying to access one of these key-value pairs, we traverse through the
linked list until the key matches.
Hash map public enemy number one: collisions.

This seems to imply that it is commonplace to search among the values for a key that maps to it, namely invert the function. In this case, of course it'd be easier if the fn were injective. However, I thought that was not a common use of a hash function/table.
In addition, I don't understand why "older keys will get overridden". For example, why is the following function f("a")=1, f("b")=1, f("c")=1, more difficult to handle than g("a")=1, g("b")=2, g("c")=3, in terms of insertion/lookup/deletion?
Edit: consider two functions. f(x)=1 for every letter x="a","b",..."z". And g("a")=1,g("b")=2,..., g("z")=26. Why is it O(1) to determine whether a given letter is a key in g, but O(n) to determine whether a given letter is a key in f? Naively, I would assume both f,g would be stored as a table of (key, val) pairs.

"This seems to imply that it is commonplace to search among the values for a key that maps to it". No. You're searching for a key/value pair that corresponds to your lookup key. The Wikipedia entry has a fairly clear explanation.

@RobbyCornelissen why is this search needed at all? Why can't my non-injective f just be stored as a function? Or a set of key-value tuples?

Not quite sure what you mean. The whole idea is that, when searching for a key, it's faster to search through a small subset of keys than to search through all the keys. The hash of the key is used to figure out which small subset to search through.

In general, the hash functions used for a hash map/table are not injective. A 'cryptographic' hash function has special properties, one of which assumes it is not technically feasible to find a collision, so you can safely treat it as if it is injective, when in fact it is not.

@SimonGoater OK thanks for that clarification, but I still don't see why injectivity is a desirable property in terms of storage or determining if a key exists. From a Leetcode quiz, "Let's say you had a terrible hash function. It just returns the number 1337. Collisions are handled with chaining. What is the average time complexity of checking if a key exists for your hash map?" Why is the complexity of checking whether a key exists greater for a constant function than an injective function?

Okay, I have to ask - have you actually read about the concept and implementation of a hash table yet? If not, you need to do that. It sounds a lot like you haven't.

The question reads like you're thinking of a hash table as a list of hash function inputs and outputs, that you look through to find the hash of an input.

@user2357112 yes, that is the spirit of my question - I am unfamiliar with this data structure. What I've read so far does not make it clear how a hash table differs in implementation from a list of inputs and outputs. For example, hash tables use buckets for the values, but it's not clear from either Wiki or the Leetcode course why distinct buckets that contain identical values are a problem. Or why g is more easily bucketed than f, for example.

A hash table isn't designed to store a hash function. It stores a key-value mapping that has nothing whatsoever to do with the hash function. The hash function is only used to decide where entries in the hash table should go.

If I want my hash table to associate the key 15 with "bagel" and 25 with "smoothie", and my hash function is "take the last digit", then this hash function says to put both of these records in bucket 5. A collision resolution strategy says how to deal with that.

@user2357112 "a key-value mapping that has nothing whatsoever to do with the hash function" Aren't these logically equivalent? A mapping is another word for a function.

@NovicePatience: Whether "mapping" and "function" are equivalent has a lot of messy nuances that aren't worth arguing about here. The point is that the association between keys and values is a completely different thing from the hash function, and entirely unrelated to the hash function. A key 15 that hashes to 5 can be mapped to the value "bagel", even though "bagel" is not 5.

@user2357112 OK, I take your point about mapping and function (eg we could store a "rule" or a list of ordered pairs). I'm still unclear about the problem of collisions. Take Wiki's diagram "Hash collision resolved by separate chaining" in its Hash Table article. There are five names total and four utilized buckets. Two names map to 152. Why can't we just use five buckets with two buckets each containing 152? Does buckets have to be a single array object, is that the implementation detail I'm missing?

@NovicePatience: It's not a bucket that contains 152. It's the 152nd bucket (zero-indexed). You can't have two buckets both be the 152nd bucket.


I was under the impression that a hash function was typically "one way" in the sense it might be easy to compute, but difficult/impossible to invert.

Being difficult/impossible to invert is a desirable characteristic for hash functions used for cryptography/security, but isn't useful for most hash tables - it mainly helps if the keys come from some untrusted source like a public website.
As an illustration, hash tables doing everyday data storage/lookup often use identity hash functions for integral types - i.e. hash(num) == num.  They leave it up to the "% bucket_count" operation to fold the key space so that any given key maps on to a specific bucket.  Even for very strong hash functions, collisions can typically be caused by this folding-over-the-buckets operation.
If we look at the Leetcode text:

When different keys convert to the same integer, it is called a collision.


They mean that hash(key1) % bucket_count() == hash(key2) % bucket_count() is a collision situation.

Without handling collisions, older keys will get overridden and data will be lost.

They mean that if you're storing data, such as by...
hash_table[key1] = value1;
hash_table[key2] = value2;

...then - in the collision case where hash(key1) % bucket_count() == hash(key2) % bucket_count() - they both initially identify the same bucket, so if no collision handling was done, it'd be equivalent to...
bucket_array[some_index] = value1;
bucket_array[some_index] = value2;

...where the second operation overwrites the value1 stored by the first operation.

There are multiple ways to handle collisions, but here we'll talk about a common one called chaining.


When using chaining, we store linked lists inside the hash map's array instead of the elements themselves. The linked list nodes store both the key and the value. If there are collisions, the collided key-value pairs are linked together in a linked list. Then, when trying to access one of these key-value pairs, we traverse through the linked list until the key matches.

This means a bucket doesn't just store a value, it stores a linked list of (key,value) pairs.  If we then do...
hash_table[key1] = value1;
hash_table[key2] = value2;

...the first operation finds an empty bucket and creates a linked list with the single entry {key1, value1}.  The second operation finds the same bucket, sees the existing entry, compares key2 to key1 and decides not to overwrite value1, and instead inserts a new linked list element {key2, value2}.


This seems to imply that it is commonplace to search among the values for a key that maps to it, namely invert the function.

No - you search amongst the keys that hash to the same bucket to see if a key you're looking (as a find or erase operation), or wanting to add, is already there.

In this case, of course it'd be easier if the fn were injective.

As a practical matter, you commonly can't reasonably create an injective function.  For example, say you're mapping people's names to seats on a bus.  You have perhaps 60 seats, but billions of currently in-use names (and a practically infinite number of possible future ones).  At best, you'll achieve a uniform distribution with 1/60th of the names hashing to each bucket, but that still leaves plenty of room for the names you're actually given to collide.


Edit: consider two functions. f(x)=1 for every letter x="a","b",..."z". And g("a")=1,g("b")=2,..., g("z")=26. Why is it O(1) to determine whether a given letter is a key in g, but O(n) to determine whether a given letter is a key in f? Naively, I would assume both f,g would be stored as a table of (key, val) pairs.

I have no idea what you're imagining here.  If f and g are both hash tables with mappings like "a" == 1, then of course the big-O average and worst-case efficiency of operations on both tables can be expected to be the same.  Again, in the "separate chaining" approach from the Leetcode discussion, they'd be stored as a table (array) of linked lists of (key, val) pairs.
It's also possible to use "open addressing" aka "closed hashing" (easily googled) and store (key, val) pairs directly in the hash table buckets, then should there be a collision, using e.g. linear or quadratic probing to find alternative buckets.  These are effectively just merging the bucket array aspect with the linked-list-of-colliding-elements aspect by having the linked list defined by some pattern of offsets from the hashed-to bucket.
